# Using Cognito AccessKeyId / SecretAccessKey to access AWS services

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

This may be a contrived example, but Im trying to understand why the temporary AccessKeyId / SecretAccessKey retrieved via a Cognito identify won't allow me to access AWS services like S3.

From a node application, I'm authenticating a user like this (as documented in https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js):

```
var authenticationData = {
            Username : params.Username,
            Password : params.Password,
        };
        var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
        var poolData = {
            UserPoolId : params.UserPoolId,
            ClientId : params.ClientId
        };
        var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
        var userData = {
            Username : params.Username,
            Pool : userPool
        };
        var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoUser(userData);

        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: function (result) {    
                cognitoUserPoolLoginProvider = 'cognito-idp.' + params.AWSRegion +  '.amazonaws.com/' + params.UserPoolId;
                var logins = {};
                logins[cognitoUserPoolLoginProvider] = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();

                AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                    IdentityPoolId : params.IdentityPoolId, 
                    Logins : logins
                });

                AWS.config.update({region: params.AWSRegion});

                AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        callback(err, null);
                        console.log(AWS.config.credentials);
                    } else {
                        var creds = {
                            AccessKeyId: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,
                            SecretAccessKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
                            SessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken,
                        }

                        callback(null, creds);
                    }
                });
            },

            onFailure: function(err) {
                callback(err, null);
            },

        });
```

When providing a valid username/password of a user in my identity pool, I am given :

- accessKeyId
- secretAccessKey
- sessionToken

So far so good.

I assumed that the `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey` would be the temporary (time-limited) AWS credentials that could be used to access services on that users behalf.

However, when I configure my AWS CLI (`aws configure`) to access an AWS service I'm getting the following error:

```
{ [InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.]
  message: 'The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.',
  code: 'InvalidAccessKeyId',
  region: null,
  time: Sat Jan 28 2017 11:52:10 GMT+0100 (CET),
  requestId: '68BB8C46F7BC195D',
  extendedRequestId: '4Z6d+MCRIiZ1CtApQfphbkWPBCO/jpI0DXqyfK5/5yKaYqwDj/OAhCgy6UJdACyuIs5UxqLPfZk=',
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 90.96230010036379 }
```

Why isn't this AWS Access Key considered a valid key ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the SessionToken to the service, too.

Temporary credentials (typically, the AccessKeyId starts with `ASIA` rather than the familiar `AKIA` -- I believe I read somewhere thar the `S` means "session" and the `K` means "key") are completely unrecognized by the service API unless accompanied, in each request, by the session token.

So why doesn't the error message say that?!

Speculation:

When temporary credentials were introduced, they weren't implemented as a pattern match on the AccessKeyId (`/^AKIA/` vs `/^ASIA/`) but were instead implemented as some kind of "hook" that diverts the authentication/authorization at the service API endpoint to an alternate code path, very early in request processing... but that this only happens when a session token is present in the request.  (On the wire, it's sent as `x-amz-security-token`.)

When that isn't the case, the request falls through to the standard code path and the credentials are validated as though they were ordinary credentials -- so the error message comes from the code path that validates standard credentials -- and for that system, the access key id indeed doesn't exist.

Comment: The knowledge about the 's' and 'k' is useful. However, even after providing the session token it gives the same error.

Comment: @SHIKHARSINGH it shouldn't give exactly the same error.  If I remember correctly, you should see something like `The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid` if there's a problem with the token.  Which AWS service are you using and which Language/SDK?

Comment: The language is java springboot framework to generate the temporary crfedentials but react to run it. This is the exact error that I recieve - Error: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

Comment: The call looks like  AWS.config.update({
          accessKeyId: "ASIA.......................",  
          secretAccessKey: "95h+3KSDbSnO...................",
          sessionToken: "FQoDYXdzEEUaDEIl8YIyFGLx71VypCKrAUShgBBUSbUPTCPPitY9+mOPWZxt7KT2eTNI+7oHAwmetBBnYYZ2/uSwon9plXExMrqlp1ABid5PihM6Nml98SQPjBz............................................C5JEWX2uy3j6q0aeLoiXI2cu339rZG0HcojWItwpgM61I5s7CeocoPPtiiOnOjZBQ==",
      });